# CVS Tagging is not working properly

Tags: repository, branch, cvs, branching-and-merging

I am using below command to create a tag from branch but tag is being created for head.

cvs -d CVSROOT_Path rtag TagName BranchName ModuleName

Is there any solution for this. Please suggest if any exists. Thanks

Comment: You need to do `... rtag -r branchName tagName ...`